# After creating inheritance tables in postgres, queries to select data from parent takes more time

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, database-partitioning

To make better performance of millions of rows in postgres, create inheritance of parent and child tables based on conditions.

```
CREATE TABLE a (id, type, measured_time, station);
CREATE TABLE a1 (CHECK (type = 001)) INHERITS a;
CREATE TABLE a2 (CHECK (type = 002)) INHERITS a;
CREATE TABLE a3 (CHECK (type = 003)) INHERITS a;
```

For selecting data, want to make query through parent table for fetching data from child table.

```
SELECT * from a 
WHERE a.type = 001 
  AND a.measured_time IN (SELECT MAX(a.measured_time) 
                          WHERE a.measured_time >= now()-interval '1 hour' 
                            AND a.measured_time < now() 
                            AND type = 001 
                            AND station = 'chicago' 
                            ORDER BY a.measured_time);
```

I'm so curious why performance for this query become worse using inheritance to treat like partition in postgres.
Welcome any good idea.

Comment: If you want to do partitioning, use [declarative partitionion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `order by` in the sub-select is completely useless

Comment: Your table definitions are syntactically incorrect, and you didn't add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: It may depends on postgresql version too. Postgresql 12 has big amount of improvements on partitionning.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I have tried with declarative partition and performance improved. But it's not convenient to upgrade postgres version easily and tried with inheritance tables that gives worse performance than simple queries. I believe it's not a good solution indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use joins instead of using **In clause** in the query.it gives the better performance